How to handle distributed locks and long-living transactions in a SAGA pattern?
I am working on a distributed system with two services:
user-order service: Handles user operations such as place-order, get-order, cancel, return, etc.
seller-order service: Manages order state changes (e.g., dispatched, delivered, or canceled) based on seller or delivery agent actions.
Use Case:
We want to allow users to prepay for a cash-on-delivery (COD) order, provided certain conditions are met:

The order has not been canceled (either by the user or the seller).
The order has not been shipped by the seller.
Future eligibility conditions might be added.

Since payment initiation is a user action, it starts in the user-order service, but the operation needs confirmation from both the user-order and seller-order services to ensure consistency. Additionally, operations like cancellation or prepaid conversion must occur in isolation to prevent conflicts.
Challenges:
Distributed Locks:

To prevent race conditions (e.g., a user canceling an order while it's being converted to prepaid), a lock mechanism is required. Currently, we create a temporary lock entry in each service's database to represent the processing state (PROCESSING) and reject conflicting actions until the lock is released.

However, this approach scales poorly:

As more services participate, each one requires its own lock mechanism, leading to redundancy.
For every new SAGA, additional tables would be required across all services.
These lock tables are temporary and require periodic cleanup, adding maintenance overhead.



Is there a better way to implement distributed locks across multiple services, ensuring isolation without redundant lock tables ?
Long-Living Locks:

Once a lock is acquired, it can only be released after all dependent services respond. For example:

The user-order service locks the order until it receives confirmation from the seller-order service.
During this time, other operations (e.g., user cancellation) are blocked, potentially frustrating users.


Introducing a timeout for locks could lead to inconsistencies:

For instance, if the lock expires in the user-order service but the seller-order service successfully converts the order to prepaid, operations in the seller-order service could occur on inconsistent data.



How can locks be made time-bounded in a SAGA pattern while ensuring system consistency? Is there a way to handle partial failures gracefully and terminate mid-way transactions without leaving any system in an inconsistent state ?
Implementation Details:
The current implementation involves the following steps:
The user-order service initiates payment conversion.
It checks if the order is already canceled. If not, it acquires a lock and publishes a check event.
The seller-order service listens for the event, acquires its lock, and verifies the order's eligibility for prepaid conversion.
Based on the result, the seller-order service publishes a reply event.
The user-order service processes the reply and either completes the conversion or initiates a refund.
I am looking for practical design recommendations or patterns to address these challenges, particularly for:
Efficiently implementing distributed locks in a multi-service environment.
Managing long-living locks or timeouts without risking data inconsistencies.
